# Small push button?

Tags: high-end

I wish to find a small pushbutton. I need to insert it into a 6mm round-ed hole (which can be expanded to 7mm max).

My desire is something like this:

[image]

However these buttons are way too big for my usage. They usually needs 19-20mm rounded holes. My whole box is 30mm tall, so I'm looking for a much smaller alternative which fits into my 6-7mm hole.

Where/what should I look around to find this?

Comment: Hello Daniel, and welcome to the Hardware Recommendations site! Looking at our ["What is Hardware?"](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) Meta post, linked from our ["What topics can I ask about here?" Help Center page](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm curious whether this button question is in-scope. The Help Center page says we're looking for "an electronic item that is, interfaces with, or connects to a computer to operate".

Comment: There's also possible concern in that Meta post that a push button would be similar to a shredder -- does it perform more than one task? We have a sister site Electrical Engineering that is also *close*, but given their [Help: on-topic page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it sounds like "shopping or buying recommendation" is off-topic.

Comment: I havent spotted that small a button in stainless.

Answer (score 3):

- digikey
- newark
- mouser electronics
- allied electronics
- parts express
- allelectronics
- amazon / ebay

something like that will first be classified under **switches** then as **pushbutton** and you want to search on sizes for as small as possible with terms such as *micro* and *miniature*.  Just a web search on those terms will give you other retailers than what i've listed.